# can I find matching percentage between two face using open cv?

Tags: opencv, ios6, ios5.1, core-image

I'm working on an iOS application that requires matching percentage between two faces. I found some examples of face recognition in opencv but I'm unable to find the percentage calculation.

Comment: How would you define "similarity" between two faces?

Comment: I'm talking about face matching algorithm. This can be similar to face recognition but here the result will show that % of A' face is similar to B's face